# Rails: Cannot connect to remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have problem with connection with my remote database.

Steps, which i did:

1) In GemFile added :

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

2) in database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
database: myname
username: myuser
password: mypass
host: myhost.nazwa.pl
port: 3305
```

3) then in console i typed:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Communicat which i got:

> Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myhost.nazwa.pl' (4)

I wanted to try if I can connect with this database using small php script:

```
<?php 
$host = 'myhost.nazwa.pl';
$database = 'myname';
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';

if ( mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) ) {
echo 'connect to mysql server *** ';
}

if ( mysql_select_db($database) ) {
echo 'open database';
}

if ( !mysql_close() ) {
echo 'cannot close connection';
exit (0);
}
?>
```

And there is no problem. I can connect, create tables, add data etc.

Could you advise me something? Where can be problem? I will be very thankful.
Regards :)

Comment: I don't see you specifying a port in the PHP script. The default MySQL port is 3306 and not 3305 as you've specified in `database.yml`

Comment: Looks like the only difference is the port number, is 3305 the default?

Comment: looks like it listens on both 3305 and 3306 (might want to firewall it later).  does your database.yml have the keys indented, or are they all on the same level.

Comment: I removed port from databyse.yml. Problem still exists. but when i log in to mysql.nazwa.pl, there is information: Serwer: myhost.nazwa.pl:3305
I have intend in database.yml

Comment: is the php script and rails/ruby on the same machine?  if you open a command prompt (on the rails machine)  and `telnet myhost.nazwa.pl 3305` does it connect / show anything

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's default port is **3306**, and you've got 3305 in your configuration for some reason. Unless you're using a custom port, leave the `port:` argument out of your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for super fast response. Unfortunately, this not solve my problem. When log in to phpmyadmin i have information: Serwer: myhost.nazwa.pl:3305

Comment: If PHP "just works" and you haven't typed in a '3305' somewhere then I would say you've misread phpmyadmin.

Comment: @lukast008 That's not specified in your PHP configuration, so I'm not sure how that could possibly work. Have you tried connecting with [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or the command-line `mysql` tool? Are you doing tests in PHP and Ruby on the same server?

Comment: No, I test Ruby from my localhost, but php is on the remote server. Thanks for all answers. I think i will try deploy my application to the server and try again.

Comment: It may be that you're simply not allowed to connect to your MySQL server remotely. Usually this is a good thing, since leaving your MySQL port open is asking for trouble. The Ruby code should work on the server if it uses the same configuration as the PHP code.